# python dataframe inner join by time period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two datadrames

```
df A
index time                  col1
0     2020-10-31 16:30:30   10
1     2020-10-31 16:40:30   40

df B
index time                  col2
0     2020-10-31 16:31:30   10
```

I want to inner join these df by the time diff is < 2 minutes, for example, row 1 in df A will join with row 1 in df B, for they're only 1 min diff.
How can I set the condition to join these dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's only 1 value for every 2 minutes, you could try using [.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

**Example code:**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create sample data as in example given
textA = """
time                  col1
2020-10-31T16:30:30   10
2020-10-31T16:40:30   40
"""

textB = """
time                  col2
2020-10-31T16:31:30   10
"""

# put sample data in dataframes
dfA = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textA), header=0, sep='\s+')
dfB = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textB), header=0, sep='\s+')
dfA['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfA['time'])
dfB['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfB['time'])

# for resampling the index needs to be a datetime
dfA = dfA.set_index('time')
dfB = dfB.set_index('time')

# resample rows to every 2 minutes
dfA = dfA.resample('2min').mean()
dfB = dfB.resample('2min').mean()

# join dataframes based on resampled time
# and drop all rows that only have na values
dfA.join(dfB).dropna(how='all')
```